# Copy part of data from one table to another C#

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-3.0

I have following table. I ran this query to get student with score over 90:

```
Select Name, Class, Score from Student where Score > 90
Student
Name    Class   Rank    Score
A   1   20  100 
B   1   12  95
C   2   11  89
D   1   14  60
...
```

Now i want to move the data collected to another table called ExcellentStudent, like this:

```
ExcellentStudent
Name    Class   Score
A   1   100
B   1   95
```

Is there a simple way to do this in c#?

Comment: The first dataset you say is returned by the query but it contains `Score`s which are less than 90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# code to run the insert query against the db

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var objConnection = new SqlConnection("Your Conneciton String"))
            {
                objConnection.Open();
                using (var objCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ExcellentStudent (Name, Class, Score) SELECT Name, Class, Score FROM Student WHERE Score > 90", objConnection))
                {
                    objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                objConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can run a SQL statement to get the scores, why now call another SQL in your C# code to populate the data to the `ExcellentStudent` table?

```
INSERT INTO ExcellentStudent(Name, Class, Score)
Select Name, Class, Score from Student where Score > 90
```

Comment: You think this is most efficient way to do for record over 3000 rows?

Comment: @NoviceMe Now you are talking about performance. Compared with implementing C# logic, SQL query reduces the round trips between your App and SQL server. So it is more efficient. You can also try the [merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command, it is expected to be a bit faster. I am an ORM guy, but if you want to improve the performance of your App, you should stick with SQL.

Comment: Yes @sza is correct to keep speed at it's fastest always use a direct SQL query.  Of course this isn't always possible but in this case it is.